# Module dependency not detected during compile in IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am developing an Android app and I'm trying to include [GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) to plot some graphs.

It is required to include it as a module dependency. After I do that, the IntelliJ IDE properly detects the packages and I can import them, but compiler throws errors when trying to compile:

- package com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView does not exist
- cannot find symbol class GraphView

etc.

I followed this guide to include it: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Sharing_and_re-using_Android_resources_through_library_projects

Comment: Could you found a solution to this. Right now I'm struggling with the same problem. IntelliJ is detecting the libraries but they seem to be missing in compilation. I'm stuck with Eclipse, which compiles fine but it's really sluggish.

Comment: Sadly I gave up on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it still occures to anyone , for me the reason was that the module's Android class libarary  source folder was not marked as 'Sources' directory .
Simply click on the sources folder and choose mark directory as --> source folder. 
After that instead of compile , choose 'make' , and then it will start working for you.

Best of luck with that annoying bug !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it:

I was using Gradle so I right-clicked on the `build.gradle.kts` (it may just be `build.gradle` in your case) and clicked on "Import Gradle project" and everything worked again!