# Module packages not found at compile time in IntelliJ

Tags: android, compilation, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to setup my Android project in IntelliJ. I've never used it before, and I'm having some problems with module dependencies.

The project depends on several modules, which I have added in the Dependencies tab. IntelliJ detects them (i.e. there are no complaints in the code), but it fails at compile time with "package x.y.z does not exist." I have also tried checking "export" for the modules, but that seems to have no effect.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9453900/210070) which appears to be the same problem, but there was no solution.

Comment: Scope is set at Compile?

Comment: You have it set up as an Android project from scratch or trying to import as such, versus a standard Java project? The problem areas are 3rd party jars or src?

Comment: I imported the project (from an Eclipse project), likewise for the modules. They are all src and not jars. "Library module" is checked for all the modules in the Android facet.

Comment: Try the steps in my posted answer, perhaps that will force inclusion/compilation for you, was a bit long to make a comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding your src as modules.

- File > Add Module
- Create Module from Existing Sources -> your_src_path_top_level
- Next > Next > Finish
- File > Project Structure > Modules > YourApp
- plus button > Module Dependency > your_lib_you_added_earlier
- Use the up/down arrows to move  to the bottom of the
  list

Here is a visual where I have added the Google Play src as a module.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm using IntelliJ 12, so it was slightly different. File > New Module > Android > Library Module > Content root > module_top_level.